# python3.9 on WSL2+ Ubuntu 20.04: How to display image using cv2 (opencv-python 4.4.0.46)

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, imshow

I am running python3.9 on WSL2+ Ubuntu 20.04. I have also installed opencv-python 4.4.0.46.

Now, I am trying to use cv2.imshow to display the image. However, it seems that WSL would not allow the display and saving may be one of the option.

I would like to know if someone has managed to achieve the display of image/plot within cv2. If yes, I would appreciate some help.

UPDATE:
The output of print(cv2.getBuildInformation()):

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.4.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.4.0-dirty

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2020-11-03T00:52:03Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.15.0-1077-gcp x86_64
    CMake:                       3.18.2
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (29 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (4 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/c++  (ver 9.3.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/cc
    C flags (Release):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed
    ccache:                      YES
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          ade Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent /lib64/libpng.so /lib64/libz.so dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf libjpeg-turbo libwebp libtiff libjasper IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java js python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI:
    QT:                          YES (ver 5.15.0)
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.7)
    JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.5-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /lib64/libpng.so (ver 1.5.13)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build Jasper (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.109.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.61.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.60.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.8.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.8/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.8/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/python/cp38-cp38/bin/python (ver 3.8.6)
    Libraries:                   libpython3.8.a (ver 3.8.6)
    numpy:                       /tmp/pip-build-env-qru8fff1/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.3)
    install path:                python

  Python (for build):            /bin/python2.7

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.8/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Update 2:

I got OpenCV working for GUI plotting as well; however, there are still minor hitches.

What I did:

1. Download and install VcXsrv
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install python3.8-tk (you may have to install a different python*-tk depnding on the python version you're using)
4. Added following line to
   ~/.bashrc
   export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0
   export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
   sudo /etc/init.d/dbus start &> /dev/null

This has got Matplotlib working flawlessly. Also, imshow using OpenCV works fine; but, I get the following message:

QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x5595c0dbcfe0) is not the object's thread (0x5595c035df40).
Cannot move to target thread (0x5595c0dbcfe0)

I actually get ~50 replica of the same message and hence, it's annoying.

Also, since I am plotting using Matplotlib, followed by imshow using OpenCV, VcXsrv only displays second image when I close the first pot by Matplotlib.

This is th code snippet that I am running:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.show()

import cv2

# load our example image
orig = cv2.imread("beagle.png")
print("Image loaded")
# display our input image
cv2.imshow("Image", orig)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: please explain what what package of opencv for python you are using

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz , I have installed opencv-python 4.4.0.46. Thanks a lot for your willingness to help.

Comment: where did you get that package from? run `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())` from python. add the output to your post.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz , I updated the information in the original posting.

Comment: ok so the problem seems to be that WSL 2 needs "a Windowing system and a Display server" to actually show anything. please investigate what you need to make things running under WSL 2 have access to the display. random result from google: https://itnext.io/using-windows-10-as-a-desktop-environment-for-linux-7b2d8239f2f1

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, thanks a lot. I got OpenCV working for GUI plotting as well; however, there are still minor hitches. Please have a look at the second update to the original post.